# Получить текст процедуры до внесения в нее изменений ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Для того чтобы вести журнал изменений в базе данных, нужно получить текст процедуры до и после изменений. Получить текст процедуры после изменений не такая уж и проблема, а вот как вытянуть до изменений никак не могу понять.

Answer (score 2):

```
select name, text from syscomments s join sysobjects o on s.id=o.id
where name='имя процедуры'
```

Comment: Кажется вы не поняли, либо я не достаточно явно обрисовал вопрос. Необходимо - при изменении процедуры(например), внести в отдельную таблицу текст этой самой процедуры до изменения и после.

Comment: Возможно, что не понял. Я исходил из того, что вы просто дважды  выполните insert... select до и после изменения процедуры. Ваш комментарий не добавил мне понимания.

Comment: Попробую переформулировать. Что я хочу получить по итогу: таблица которая будет содержать в себе 4 поля(для примера): имя процедуры, дата изменения процедуры, старое тело процедуры, новое тело процедуры. Т.е. мне необходимо получить тело процедуры до того как ее кто либо изменит.

Comment: @idrees, в DDL-триггере вроде бы нельзя получить предыдущее тело процедуры. И потом, даже если бы это было возможно - так у вас будет храниться избыточная информация. Пусть, например, хранятся записи _(procName, date1, body1, body2); (procName, date2, body2, body3); (procName, date3, body3, body4)_, при этом, заметьте, _body2_ и _body3_ хранятся два раза. Храните лучше имя, дату и текущее тело, предыдущее тело легко будет достать запросом.

Comment: @i-one, Именно, ddl не умеет такого. Простите, это каким таким запросом я могу получить предыдущее тело? проведу последовательность: Была создана ХП(много) -> Был создан триггер отслеживающий изменения ХП -> кто-то изменил одну из ХП -> триггер записывает в отдельную табл. данные об изменении. Вопрос, как я могу получить тело ХП до изменения? "Храните лучше имя, дату и текущее тело, предыдущее тело легко будет достать запросом." если верно понимаю, то следуя вашему совету, я могу получить только предыдущее измененное тело(если ХП была изменена 2 раза).

Comment: @idrees, _"проведу последовательность..."_, скорее так: Есть ХП(много) -> Создали триггер и таблицу для логгирования (её заполнили начальными данными  - существующими ХП) -> какая-то ХП (условно _P1(ver.1)_) изменилась -> триггер записывает изменениe (_P1(ver.2)_ и дату), в логе для _P1_ теперь две записи (_ver.2_ и начальная _ver.1_) -> ХП _P1_ снова меняется -> триггер записывает изменениe (_P1(ver.3)_ и дату), в логе для _P1_ теперь три записи (_ver.3, ver.2, ver.1_). При удалении ХП пишем _NULL_ или удаляем историю (смотря что требуется).

Comment: То, что Вы описали это фактически source control. Это никак не дело БД, а дело разработчиков - собраться, обсудить как хранить старые и новые скрипты.